# Updating state of class members does not deliver correct values

Tags: c++, loops, class, state

I ran into a little problem here, and I'm kind of stuck, tried googling it but couldn't find a solution that helped. Hopefully somebody here can help.

So I have this little class here. I'm trying to initialize Button members in a loop and push the created members to a vector named btns. I thought this way I can update the button members in a method by just looping through the btns vector and call each of the members update function. The button.update() function basically just sets a state to this point.

So far this works quite good, or at least every Button gets its correct init values. I run into the weird behaviour when I want to call the button.update() function. As I already mentioned, every button has a boolean member called "state" that gets initialized with the value false. For the test purpose, I tried to set the state of a button to true with the button.update() method. The problem is now, when I try to check if the update worked and read back the value of state, I only get back true if I call the button.update() method in the same scope as the read back. If I want to get the value of state later, it comes back as false, and I really can't understand or explain why.

This is the class I'm talking of:

```cpp
#include <ucRP2040.hpp>

ucRP2040::ucRP2040(std::vector<u8_t> btns, std::vector<u8_t> leds)
{
    for (u8_t pin : btns)
    {
        Button btn(pin);
        // btns here is a std::vector<Button>
        this->btns.push_back(btn);
    }
}

void ucRP2040::update()
{
    /*Input*/
    for (Button btn : btns)
    {
        btn.update();
    }

    for (Button btn : btns)
    {
        // btn.update(); <- if I uncomment this line, state works    
        Serial.print(" state: ");
        //only works if btn.update() was called in loop scope 
        Serial.println(btn.state); //gives back false       

        //This works correct
        Serial.print("size: ");
        Serial.print(btns.size());
        Serial.print(" pin: ");
        Serial.print(btn.pin);
    }
 
    // This does not work at all, gives back false
    Serial.println(btn[0].state);

    delay(500);

}
```

This is the Button class:

```cpp
#include <Button.hpp>

Button::Button(u8_t pin) : pin{pin}, state{false}
{
}

void Button::update()
{

    state = true;
}
```

This is my main:

```cpp
#include <ucRP2040.hpp>
#include <Arduino.h>

// USER BUTTON abd LEDs
std::vector<u8_t> usrbtns = {13, 14, 15};
std::vector<u8_t> usrleds = {22, 23, 24, 25};

// INIT HW
ucRP2040 ucrp2040(usrbtns, usrleds);

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
    ucrp2040.update();
}
```

I tried to break it down and leave comments in the code, maybe this is more self-explanatory. Has anybody a clue what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: please add the .hpp file of button too and the ucRP2040 one too

Answer (score 2):

```
    for (Button btn : btns)
```

This is range iteration ***by value***. In the `for` loop, the `btn` object is a ***copy*** of each value in the `btns` container.

```
btn.update();

// ...

void Button::update()
{

    state = true;
}
```

This modifies the `btn` object. And at the end of the loop, `btn` gets destroyed. It disappears. It becomes no more. It ceases to exist. It starts pining for the fjords. It becomes an ex-`Button`.

Instead, iteration by reference should be used in order to update each value in the array:

```
    for (Button &btn : btns)
```

Now, `btn` will be a ***reference*** to each value in the `btns` container, iterating over it.

The other `for` range iteration will likely need the same change. Even if it doesn't modify each `Button` object this will likely optimize out an utterly useless copy of each `Button` that happens when iterating by value.

This is no different than passing parameters to a function. As you know, parameters get passed by value, and each parameter in the function is a ***copy*** of the passed-in object; while a reference function parameter ends up passing by reference. Same thing.

Comment: You shot my failure to the moon! Thanks Sam, that helped a lot!